# Installing opencv + fatal error: 'opencv2/core.hpp' file not found

Tags: opencv

I have installed open cv using the official installation process given at:

https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d0/db2/tutorial_macos_install.html

I am doing this on mac and it took ~3 hours for this process. After installation, the installed directory looks like this:

```
apple@Apples-MacBook-Air.local:~/Learning/openCV/cpp$  pwd
/Users/apple/Learning/openCV/cpp

apple@Apples-MacBook-Air.local:~/Learning/openCV/cpp$  ls
3rdparty            CTestTestfile.cmake     bin             data                 
opencv_data_config.hpp      setup_vars.sh
CMakeCache.txt          Makefile            cmake_install.cmake     doc              
opencv_lapack.h         test-reports
CMakeDownloadLog.txt        OpenCVConfig-version.cmake  cmake_uninstall.cmake        
include             opencv_python_config.cmake  tmp
CMakeFiles          OpenCVConfig.cmake      configured          lib              
opencv_python_tests.cfg     unix-install
CMakeVars.txt           OpenCVModules.cmake     custom_hal.hpp          modules              
opencv_tests_config.hpp     version_string.tmp
CPackConfig.cmake       apps                cv_cpu_config.h         opencv               
python_loader
CPackSourceConfig.cmake     basicOp.cpp         cvconfig.h          opencv2         
samples
```

Now, I am writing a very simple program to test the installation and it looks like that I need to do more things than what I have done so far.

My simple program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<opencv2/core.hpp>

int main() {
  std::string imagePath = samples.findFile("starry_night.jpg");
  cv::Mat imageMatrix   = cv::imread(imagePath);
  if(imageMatrix.empty()) {
    std::cout << "Matrix is empty" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Compiling this gives error as:

```
apple@Apples-MacBook-Air.local:~/Learning/openCV/programs$  g++ imageRead.cpp 
 imageRead.cpp:2:9: fatal error: 'opencv2/core.hpp' file not found
 #include<opencv2/core.hpp>
```

No problem, I can probably understand that due to non-linkage of the open cv libraries.

So, I compiled with:

```
apple@Apples-MacBook-Air.local:~/Learning/openCV/programs$  g++ imageRead.cpp -I/Users/apple/Learning/openCV/cpp/include -L/Users/apple/Learning/openCV/cpp/lib/
```

imageRead.cpp:2:9: fatal error: 'opencv2/core.hpp' file not found
#include<opencv2/core.hpp>

And it still give me the same error. Basically, I passed the paths for gcc to consider for linking.

Any suggestions? I can help providing more details on it, if needed.

Comment: probably there should be another folder opencv4 in the include directoty: `-I/Users/apple/Learning/openCV/cpp/include/opencv4`

Comment: @Miki, Thanks for your reply and I see your point. Unfortunately, what you are saying does not exists.

[apple@Apples-MacBook-Air.local:~/Learning/openCV/programs$  ls /Users/apple/Learning/openCV/cpp/include/
CMakeFiles  CTestTestfile.cmake Makefile  cmake_install.cmake

Comment: then that's not the correct include folder. have a look where you installed opencv (with make install)

Comment: @Miki, Ok. I did make -j at `/Users/apple/Learning/openCV/cpp/`. And the directory contents of that are already written in the question. What is your point of not trusting me here? :)

Comment: with that command you build opencv, but you never installed it. You need "make install" to install opencv (it will be installed in the CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX folder, which by default is /usr/local or something like that. So run "make install" (or "sudo make install"), and look in that folder

Comment: you needn't install it, but then you need to tell the compiler and linker where to find the stuff (compiler: include dirs, linker: library dirs and library names). questions aren't about trust, they're about guessing what could be wrong, and covering that. the paths must be precisely right. and you need to show us what exactly is in those directories (and potentially the subdirectories).

Comment: @Miki, I see your point. As Christoph wrote, it is not necessary to install. You can just point to the right set of paths and you should be good to go.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, Thanks for your valuable comment. I understand your first point not the second point where you are asking content. What exactly are you asking for? I tried to write that in the question itself.

Comment: @Miki, Btw, even after doing make install. I still see the similar problem. This is what I see after doing make install.

`...
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/opencv4/lbpcascades/lbpcascade_silverware.xml
-- Installing: /usr/local/bin/opencv_annotation
...
`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>` instead of `#include<opencv2/core.hpp>`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Let me put a smiley here. :) Actually I was doing opencv.hpp itself. Then I tried, core/opencv.hpp. While pasting it here, I remove opencv instead of core.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. this answer should probably have been a *comment* under the question, not an *answer*.